# Case insensitive sorting

Tags: vim, sorting

Vim's default sort is case sensitive, and produces results like this:

```
A
B
a
```

How can it be made case-insensitive, to produce the following result given the same input?

```
A
a
B
```

Comment: what about to use `sort -f` eventually redirecting output to a new file `sort -f old_file > new_file`?

Comment: I assume you mean case sensitive in the first one?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Vim's own `:sort` command

```
:%sort i
```

does what you want.

See `:help :sort`.

Alternatively, you can also use your system's `sort` command as a filter:

```
:%!sort -f
```

See `:help filter` in Vim and `$ man sort` in your shell.

Comment: What's different between `:%sort i` and `:sort i`?

Comment: No fundamental difference. The former is explicit about the range on which it operates on while the latter is implicit.